# numpy error cannot perform reduce with flexible type when reading data from list and not array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, regression

I am trying to do a simple regression analysis by reading cols from a csv file and using numpy and stats to do the regression analysis. The code works all the way to print x or y but it gives an error on the last line of code

```
 line 62, in _mean
    ret = um.add.reduce(arr, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I believe the error lie in me putting a list within the asarray function. if i manually put in the data into the asarray function, the code works but i want to read directly from a csv file.

Here is my code:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pylab
import csv
import sys

cr = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1],"rU").readlines()[2:])
off_signups=[]
off_cost=[]

for row in cr:
    off_signups.append(row[1])
    off_cost.append(row[2])

x=np.asarray(off_signups)
y=np.asarray(off_cost)

print x
print y

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, slope_std_error = stats.linregress(x, y)
```

Comment: Since we don't know what `x` and `y` are, we can't tell what the actual problem is. x or y is probably a *flexible* data type, not something like a (numpy.)float, numpy.double, bool or int; but an object ('O') or similar. Perhaps x and/or y are arrays of strings instead of numbers?

Comment: Also, you should post the full traceback; that may actually shed a bit more light on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to Python so am not the expert.... 
But I tried

```
a = np.asarray([1, 4, 5, 8], float)
```

This helped me out here.